# Removing a bean from the ViewAccessScope

Tags: jsf-2, codi

This is with MyFaces CODI JSF-Module v1.0.1 for JSF 2.0

I have JSF page that uses a @ViewAccessScoped backing bean and it does pretty much what I want it to, except it doesn't go away when I am done with it.  The page is invoked from another page like this:

```
  <h:link outcome="/editLocation" target="_blank" 
       value="Edit Location: #{maintLocation.selected.id}"
       disabled="#{!maintLocation.rowSelected}">                               
          <f:param name="locationID" value="#{maintLocation.selected.id}" />
          <f:param name="closeOnUpdate" value="true" />
  </h:link>
```

The user experience is that the **editLocation** page pops up in a new window or new tab, the user edits it, and on completion it calls **window.close()** if the **closeOnUpdate** parameter is set true.

That all works.  But if the user edits *another* location the **ViewAccessScoped** bean is still there so it doesn't get re-instantiated.  As such it never sees the parameters and simply comes up with the state that it is in with the prior record.

By manually erasing the **windowid** parameter in the browser URL window I can get a new backing bean.  Is there a way to remove this from the **h:link** component?

Alternatively, is there a way for the bean to remove itself from the scope that it is in once it hits the complete button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on [the CODI Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-TerminatingConversations).  Although I am not implicitly using CODI Conversations, the @ViewAccessScoped implementation seems to be layered on top of it.  So I could do:

```
import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.Conversation;

...

@Inject private Conversation conversation;

...

conversation.close();  // when I have committed to close the window.
```

Comment: Like some other CODI-Scopes @ViewAccessScoped is just a special type of conversation.